# How to put programmatically iCarousel in View?

Tags: uiscrollview, iphone-sdk-4.3

I want four ScrollViews like [iCarousel](https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel)'s CoverFlow in View programmatically. My Code is

```
    // Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];

        //set up data
        wrap = YES;
        self.items = [NSMutableArray array];
        for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_ITEMS; i++)
        {
            [items addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:i]];
        }

        carousel1 = [[carousel1 alloc] init];
carousel2 = [[carousel2 alloc] init];
carousel3 = [[carousel3 alloc] init];
carousel4 = [[carousel4 alloc] init];

        carousel1.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 120);
        carousel2.frame = CGRectMake(0, 120, 320, 120);
carousel3.frame = CGRectMake(0, 240, 320, 120);
carousel4.frame = CGRectMake(0, 360, 320, 120);

        carousel1.delegate = self;
carousel2.delegate = self;
carousel3.delegate = self;
carousel4.delegate = self;

        carousel1.dataSource = self;
carousel2.dataSource = self;
carousel3.dataSource = self;
carousel4.dataSource = self;
        [self.view addSubview:carousel1];
[self.view addSubview:carousel2];
[self.view addSubview:carousel3];
[self.view addSubview:carousel4];

        //configure carousel
        carousel1.type = iCarouselTypeCoverFlow2;
carousel2.type = iCarouselTypeCoverFlow2;
carousel3.type = iCarouselTypeCoverFlow2;
carousel4.type = iCarouselTypeCoverFlow2;

    }
```

but fail with four warnings with out placing the carousels view on the View. Please help me to overcome this problem. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't you be initialising them with [[iCarousel alloc] init] instead of [[carousel1 alloc] init]?